# Como criar uma conexão com um db externo com um app Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, apache-cordova

Estou entrando e estudando o mundo do Phonegap/Cordova e quero começar a desenvolver aplicativos mais legais e com mais interação, mas estou encontrando essa limitação, na maioria dos locais onde eu encontro para aprender, os bancos de dados para as aplicações utilizando Phonegap/Cordova são locais e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma aplicação utilizando essas ferramentas(de forma segura) com um banco de dados externo e se sim, como fazer.

obs: já encontrei perguntas com respostas aqui mesmo que diziam que era possível realizar a conexão com o banco com o JS, mas em contrapartida, isso não era seguro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diretamente no lado cliente não é possível conectar diretamente no banco de dados.

No lado servidor, com javascript temos o NodeJS que faz essa conexão. Ou mesmo pode usar várias outras linguagens como ASP.NET, PHP, Java, Python, Ruby (on Rails) etc.

O que se utiliza é criar um WebService REST (mais fácil) ou WebSocket (menos utilizado) para a comunicação do servidor com a aplicação cliente.

Uma vez tendo o servidor, o cliente pode se comunicar com http ou websocket para trocar dados com o servidor e assim com o banco de dados.

Existem várias alternativas dependendo do framework javascript que você for usar se você for usar um.

Procure por WebServices e requisições AJAX.

Comment: Obrigado Shura16

Answer (score 0):

Olá, uma opção muito legal que deixa transparente pra você essa parte de XHR e ajax e tem todo um back-end à sua disposição é o [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com//), um serviço do google que pode ser acessado com javascript. Dá uma olhada lá..